# Using logical operators in the domain constraints of functions

Tags: functions, logic

Is it 'mathematically correct' or 'acceptable' to use logical operators when defining the domain of a function?

Say, I have

$$f(x,y)=\frac{\sqrt{x^2+y-1}}{x^2-1},$$

then for its domain, I will have

$$\text{dom}\ f=\left\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2\ \Big|\ y\geq1-x^2\text{ and }x\neq\pm1\right\}.$$

Is it okay to write $y\geq1-x^2\wedge x\neq\pm1,$ instead of $y\geq1-x^2\text{ and }x\neq\pm1$?

Comment: I think it’s okay. Set definition notation in a rare example where we already expect a lot of notation.  I’m a stickler for avoiding most symbols in the middle of sentences, but here it doesn’t bother me. But others may differ.

Comment: It is ok. However, the key thing is that your reader understand easily what you mean. I’m not sure that replacing $\text{and}$ with $\wedge$ goes in that direction.

Comment: Okay. Understood! I guess I'll continue using $\wedge$ since I'm mostly doing this in writing my solutions for my undergrad problems. Thanks a lot!